# axios post to different port on same domain without specifying domain

Tags: axios

I need axios to communicate with a backend system on the same domain with a different port, and I do not wish to configure the full domain name. There are a lot of VERY similar questions on SO but nothing with an answer that quite addresses a frontend web app calling the backend on a different port without specifying the domain.

In a constants file I have

```
import axios from 'axios'
   
export const AXIOS = axios.create({
    baseURL: ":8080/foo" // this does not work, it posts to http://localhost/:8080/foo
});
```

then in the code I import my AXIOS constant and do something like

```
AXIOS.post(url, json)
```

The frontend app is being served from http://localhost

The backend code is listening on http://localhost:8080/foo

Nothing I have tried so far has given me a correct backend url short of specifying the fully qualified domain name. I see this has been discussed on the axios project at https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/187 and was closed because "we don't support specifying other granular urls parts as host or protocol and it can be implemented in user-land" though they were non-specific as to how user-land might implement this.

The only solution I have come up with is one that I find inellegant, I can use javascript to figure out what URL the front end is running on and hack that apart as a string to come up with a complete URL on the desired port. Please don't make me do that.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a better answer than to take the origin and manipulate it.

Here's an approach I'd use - have this all contained within an ApiClient and then that client has a single `baseUrl`. That way you can re-use it and the `baseURL` is nicely encapsulated and doesn't leak outside of the implementation.

Here I make a private `baseUrl` and use the URL helper class to set the port.

Then inside `GetThing()` we use `new URL(path, BASE_URL)` and call `href` to get the joined `string` version of the URL. I find this to be super neat (I use it often in our apps).

This will return `https://example.com/my/path`:

```
new URL("my/path", "https://example.com").href;
```

Example client:

```
import axios from "axios";

class ApiClient {
  constructor() {
    this.baseUrl = new URL(document.location.origin);
    this.baseUrl.port = 8080;
  }

  async GetThing() {
    const url = new URL("/thing", this.baseUrl).href;
    const result = await axios({
      url,
      // method, etc
    });
    return result.data;
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
const client = new ApiClient();
const thing = await client.GetThing();
```

Or you can pass options into a client if you modify it to take an options param:

```
...
  constructor(options) {
    this.baseUrl = new URL(document.location.origin);
    this.baseUrl.port = options.port ?? 8080;
  }
...

const client = new ApiClient({ port: 8000 });
```